# How can I figure out where packets are going when connected to VPN?

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have a server, I've connected to VPN. And made it [accessible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242808/29867) with these two commands:

```
ip rule add table 128 from server.ip
ip route add table 128 default via def.gw
```

Since VPN provider pushes these commands:

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via vpn.gw
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via vpn.gw
```

But when I do `traceroute` from the server, I get VPN's gateway as the first hop. It's as if those two commands didn't have an effect. Although, they certainly did, since I'm able to ssh to the server.

What am I missing? How to see where packets are going?

Comment: 0.0.0.0/1 is going to route half the whole IPv4 address space to your VPN gateway, so it wouldn't surprise me that you'd see that as the first hop. My CIDR is a little rusty, but I'm not at all uncertain that 128.0.0.0/1 doesn't route the OTHER half of the IPv4 address space to your vpn gateway.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy The idea behind two routes (`0.0.0.0/1`, `128.0.0.0/1`) instead of one (`0.0.0.0/0` or `default`) is that those two routes are more specific, and no need to remove the default route user had before connecting to VPN. But, on one hand, since I'm able to connect to my server, packets coming from my server return back via hoster's gateway. On the other hand, `traceroute` shows that packets coming from my server go via VPN's gateway. There must be something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `traceroute`'s turned out to be a good way to check where packets are going. It's just that with `openvpn` running packets coming to `eth0` seem to disappear when server (not VPN server) makes a routing decision. Unless you do some [voodoo magic](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/05/msg00780.html).